# Why are points being generated outside of a my triangle in C++?

Tags: c++, geometry

So I've read this formula generates a uniform random point inside of a triangle, from this article... http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~funk/tog02.pdf

```
        P = (1 - sqrt(R1)) * A + (sqrt(R1) * (1 - R2)) * B + (sqrt(R1) * R2) * C
```

Where...
R1 & R2 are random floats in between 0 and 1.

A, B, & C are the points that create our triangle.

I've implemented this formula in my code with MANY test conditions, expecting each condition to have a point generated in the triangle... However, there always seems to be a few cases of it outside the triangle.

Here is my code (in C++)...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

class Location
{
public:
   Location(
      int x,
      int y)
   {
      m_x = x;
      m_y = y;
   }

   int m_x;
   int m_y;

private:

};

double RandomValueBetweenZeroAndOne()
{
   return ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));
}

float GetArea(
   float x1, float y1,
   float x2, float y2,
   float x3, float y3)
{
   return abs((x1*(y2 - y3) + x2*(y3 - y1) + x3*(y1 - y2)) / 2.0f);
}

bool InsideTriangle(
   float Ax, float Ay,
   float Bx, float By,
   float Cx, float Cy,
   float Px, float Py)
{
   /* Calculate area of triangle ABC */
   float A = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PBC */
   float A1 = GetArea(Px, Py, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PAC */
   float A2 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Px, Py, Cx, Cy);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PAB */
   float A3 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Px, Py);

   /* Check if sum of A1, A2 and A3 is same as A */
   if ((A == (A1 + A2 + A3)))
   {
      return true;
   }

   return false;
};

int main()
{
   srand(time(0));

   Location* A = new Location(-54900, 933200);
   Location* B = new Location(-62800, 934300);
   Location* C = new Location(-70000, 932100);

   bool in_triangle = true;
   int i = 0;
   do
   {
      float R1 = static_cast<float>(RandomValueBetweenZeroAndOne());
      float R2 = static_cast<float>(RandomValueBetweenZeroAndOne());

      float random_x = (1.0f - sqrt(R1)) * static_cast<float>(A->m_x) + (sqrt(R1) * (1.0f - R2)) * static_cast<float>(B->m_x) + (sqrt(R1) * R2) * static_cast<float>(C->m_x);
      float random_y = (1.0f - sqrt(R1)) * static_cast<float>(A->m_y) + (sqrt(R1) * (1.0f - R2)) * static_cast<float>(B->m_y) + (sqrt(R1) * R2) * static_cast<float>(C->m_y);

      in_triangle = InsideTriangle(
         static_cast<float>(A->m_x), static_cast<float>(A->m_y),
         static_cast<float>(B->m_x), static_cast<float>(B->m_y),
         static_cast<float>(C->m_x), static_cast<float>(C->m_y),
         random_x, random_y);

      if (!in_triangle)
      {
         printf("Point located outside of Triangle on %i iteration", i);
      }
      i++;
   } while (in_triangle);

   system("pause");
}
```

In one example... The equation assigned the random coordinates as follows:

```
random_x = -66886;
random_y = 932326;
```

I even made a C# program to verify if the point was truley outside of the triangle (visually). Here's the results, everything above the line that is visible is INSIDE of the triangle... Everything Below the line that is visible is OUTSIDE of the triangle...

[https://puu.sh/rJtSJ/7a7a88c346.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SytLB.png)

For reference, I know that I can just wrap the number generating in a do while loop until a value inside the triangle is generated... I just wanted to know why it's generating outside when it's not supposed to be, and where the bug is...

Comment: For reference, I know that I can just wrap the number generating in a do while loop until a value inside the triangle is generated... I just wanted to know why it's generating outside when it's not supposed to be, and where the bug is...

Comment: About the code in general: `Location* A = new Location(-54900, 933200);` Such things are completely unnecessary and an additional possibility for bugs. Don't "write C# in C++".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @deviantfan.... Are you referring to the fact that I made it a pointer? This is a small snippet of a large collection of work, the reason it is a pointer is because it is then shared among several objects. So rather than copy the location 5-6 times, we create a pointer to it.

Comment: The truncation of the "Interpolation" to integers could be the problem.

Comment: @MartinR I was thinking that too, so I rounded the random_x and random_y values prior to the casting using ceil, as well as the GetArea resultant using ceil again before the casting (to avoid truncation)... The result was still the same. Sometimes a random coordinate set is generated that is outside of the triangle, which to my understanding should not happen.

Comment: I did not check your code, but I strongly assume that rounding the float coordinates (in either direction) can move the point outside the triangle.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains a [mcve]. Good odds that the crafting of the MCVE exposes the bug.

Comment: @user4581301 I've edited my original post as you asked.

Comment: Have you tried to use `double`s instead of `float`s?

Comment: @Bob__ I have, the same issue still happens.

Comment: @Bob__ However, it's worth noting that the variation in the resulting GetArea values is much less than when using float (along the lines of a 0.0000000001 variation or something small like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rounding problem, this needs to round down to smaller precision. Also using `double` instead of `float` will give better result.

Instead of comparing two double (or float) values to see if they are the same, take their difference and see if it is within a margin of error. The function below has arbitrary margin of `0.00001`

```
bool InsideTriangle(double Ax, double Ay, double Bx, double By, 
    double Cx, double Cy, double Px, double Py)
{
    double A = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);
    double A1 = GetArea(Px, Py, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);
    double A2 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Px, Py, Cx, Cy);
    double A3 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Px, Py);

    double diff = A1 + A2 + A3 - A;
    if (abs(diff) < 0.00001) return true;
    std::cout << diff << "\n";
    return false;
};
```

To compare the values directly, use the example below:

```
double getround(double f)
{
    return floor(f * 1000.0f + 0.5f) / 1000.0f;
}

bool InsideTriangle(double Ax, double Ay, double Bx, double By, 
    double Cx, double Cy, double Px, double Py)
{
    double A = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);
    double A1 = GetArea(Px, Py, Bx, By, Cx, Cy);
    double A2 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Px, Py, Cx, Cy);
    double A3 = GetArea(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Px, Py);
    if ((A == (A1 + A2 + A3)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    double t1 = getround(A1 + A2 + A3);
    double t2 = getround(A);

    if (t1 == t2)
        return true;
    std::cout << t1 << ", " << t2 << "\n";

    return false;
};
```

Note that you should not use cast unless the compiler complains. For example the following cast is not needed

```
float foo(){return 0.1f;}
...
float R1 = static_cast<float>(foo());
```

Because `foo` is already `float`. If you automatically put cast everywhere then it can hide potential problems.

Avoid using memory allocation when it's not need. For example, use `Location A(-54900, 933200);` instead of `new` operator. If you use `new` then be sure to free the memory with `delete` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Superb! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. See update for alternate comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic isn't perfect.That means when you do an artihmetic operation with floating points it may not give exact expected result.In that cases generally you should correct your code with wisely using a small number.
In that case part that should be corrected should be

```
float random_x = (1.0f - sqrt(R1)) * static_cast<float>(A->m_x) + (sqrt(R1) * (1.0f - R2)) * static_cast<float>(B->m_x) + (sqrt(R1) * R2) * static_cast<float>(C->m_x);
  float random_y = (1.0f - sqrt(R1)) * static_cast<float>(A->m_y) + (sqrt(R1) * (1.0f - R2)) * static_cast<float>(B->m_y) + (sqrt(R1) * R2) * static_cast<float>(C->m_y);
```

Since I didn't understand the formula I can't fix it.But if you were use that formula:

```
  if(R1+R2>1)
  {
      R1=1-R1;
      R2=1-R2;
  }
  float random_x = A->m_x+(B->m_x-A->m_x)*R1+(C->m_x-A->m_x)*R2;
  float random_y = A->m_y+(B->m_y-A->m_y)*R1+(C->m_y-A->m_y)*R2;
```

You could correct it as:

```
  if(R1+R2>1)
  {
      R1=1-R1;
      R2=1-R2;
  }
  float error=0.01;
  float D=1-error;
  float random_x = D*A->m_x+D*(B->m_x-A->m_x)*R1+D*(C->m_x-A->m_x)*R2+error*(A->m_x+B->m_x+C->m_x)/3;
  float random_y = D*A->m_y+D*(B->m_y-A->m_y)*R1+D*(C->m_y-A->m_y)*R2+error*(A->m_x+B->m_x+C->m_x)/3;
```

That will ensure points will be inside the triangle.